# Share your phone's mobile internet to a wired lan connection using Micro USB to RJ45 Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm looking for the cheapest way to use my 3g connection as a wired one. Mobile network is bit of an issue. So I put a spare phone on a higher ground  and cell reception was top notch but I can't use mobile hotspot because it won't reach my room. That's why i'm trying to reach my router using a LAN cable. 
I would also want the ability to charge my phone, possibly by using a microusb splitter?
If my solution is impossible, can you please suggest an alternative?

EDIT:
[here](http://www.amazon.in/RtsTM-RJ45-LAN-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B01K889BTO/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1493958476&sr=1-1&keywords=Micro%20USB%20to%20RJ45) is the adapter i'm talking about

EDIT: I saw people suggesting usb tethring to router's usb port but i'm talking about cheap here and cheap routers don't have usb ports :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wifi Travel adaptor with a LAN port will do what you  want - I've  got a [NetGear Trek PR2000](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/PR2000.aspx)

It has a USB port for media sharing but I use mine to to keep the phone powered not to share any media - It also serves as a Wifi Access point - but in this case you can just use the LAN port to run a cable back to the Router.  I've done this in hotels regularly when I find the hotel connection slow - I swap my phone to hotspot tell the Netgear to connect to my phone and all my other devices are still connected via the LAN port of the netgear - I have a five volt powered  Belkin switch which my laptops are connected to.

The one I bought was 120 Australian Dollars when I bought it it is probably out of sale now however this [TravelMate](http://merlin-digital.com/travelmate-wi-fi-travel-adapter.html)  seems cheaper and looks similar.

Comment: you have any idea if my solution would work?

Comment: well I had problems - I did try an adaptor like you picture - but the phone did not support the adaptor I tried - but when I found these Travel routers with WiFi sharing I stopped looking

Comment: These are fast enough - faster than most Hotels or 3G anyway, cheap, can be used to share Hotel Wifi instead of my phone and require no drivers for the phone or clients.
Also the Netgear can plug into a copper port as well and is USB powered too

Answer (score 0):

One quick alternative is to just set up a wireless bridge between the phone's hotspot and the router, which may still be able to establish a stable connection, depending on your setup.

...but I like your theoretical solution more. :)